# Creating dictionary from CSV file,

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, append, attributeerror

For the following CSV File:

```
A,B,C

A1,B1,C1
A1,B2,C2
A2,B3,C3
A2,B4,C4
```

How do I get my dictionary to look like this:

```
{'A1': {'B1': 'C1', 'B2' : 'C2'}, 'A2': {'B3': 'C3', 'B4' : 'C4'}}
```

I'm using the following code:-

```
EgDict = {}
with open('foo.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        key = row.pop('A')
        if '-' in key:
                continue
        if key not in result:
                new_row = {row.pop('B'): row.pop('C')}
                result[key] = new_row
        else:
                result[key][row.pop('B')].append(row.pop('C'))
```

I'm getting the following error:-

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

What Am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary has no `append` method. That will be for lists.

You may consider using the following code instead:

```
d = {}
with open('foo.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        d.setdefault(row['A'], {}).update({row['B']: row['C']})
print(d)
# {'A1': {'B1': 'C1', 'B2' : 'C2'}, 'A2': {'B3': 'C3', 'B4' : 'C4'}}
```

`setdefault` sets a new key with a default `{}` value when one does not exist and the update methods updates the dictionary at that key using the new values.

Comment: short and sweet. Thanks buddy :)

Comment: is there any way to store part 'C' without the quotes around it (' '). The reason I'm asking this is because C in my code is a number, and my calculations are reading it as a string because of the ''. Does that make sense?

Comment: Those are strings, if you try to remove the closing `''`, you will get a name error

Comment: How do I convert the values inside the dictionary to int, as my script currently reads these numbers in as strings. I want to use the numbers in calculations.

So it becomes:

    MyDict = {'A1': {'B1': 1, 'B2' : 2}, 'A2': {'B3': 3, 'B4' : 4}}

Comment: Can you edit the csv to reflect the `int` values instead of `'C'`s. Otherwise you may consider using `eval`, provided the CSV file was not downloaded and you're the author. The values of `'C'` must be already defined else a `NameError`

Answer (score 0):

```
res = {}
with open('foo.csv') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     for i,item in enumerate(reader):
         if i == 0: continue 
         a,b = item[0],item[1:]
         if a not in res:
            res[a] = {}
         res[a].update( {b[0]:b[1]} )
```

Comment: Instead of just code, it would be good to also have a short explanation of what you've changed and why it solves the problem.

Comment: While code-only answers are not forbidden, please understand that this is a Q&A community, rather than a crowd-sourcing one, and that, usually, if the OP understood the code being posted as an answer, he/she would have come up with a similar solution on his/her own, and wouldn't have posted a question in the first place. As such, please provide *context* to your answer and/or code by explaining *how* and/or *why* it works.